# Options for the leaflet.mouseCoordinate Plugin

Tags: leaflet

I'm using the leaflet.mouseCoordinate plugin in my map, upper right corner with an offset down about 70px. I would like to put a white background on it but changing the css like below doesn't work. Adding background:white separately also doesn't work, how do I do this?

```
.leaflet-control-mouseCoordinate{
    right: 10px; 
    width:400px;   
    min-height:30px;
    text-align:left;
    border: 3px solid #8AC007;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    background:white no-repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#b60707;
    top: 70px;
    padding:6px 10px 6px 6px}.leaflet-control-mouseCoordinate table{width:100%}.coords{width:145px}
```

Second question about this plugin: how might I make it dragable in the map? Its kind of a large display as it is, if it could be moved as the users needs it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the easiest way is to create another css with the same name in the document, and make the changes there.